# My TaskCompletetion code for performance

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task

I have been developing an ios app with Xamarin.iOS. We have a WCF service, and i use dynamic proxy which credated by silverlight tool slsvcutil, so all service methods are async now.

I call these methods but I am not sure if i am do it in the best way. Because It seems a bit weird for me. I am using taskcompletetion class first time. I found some examples that are similar to my code.

Here just a code that how I call a function and getting result

```
var folderItemListResult = Task.Run(() => search.GetFolderContent(folder));
folderItemListResult.Wait();
folderItemList = folderItemListResult.Result;
```

and this is getfoldercontent method

```
public Task<List<FolderItem>> GetFolderContent(FolderProfile folder)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<List<FolderItem>>();

    service.GetFolderItemsCompleted += (sender, args) =>
    {
        try
        {

            if (args.Result != null)
                tcs.TrySetResult(args.Result.ToList());
            else
                tcs.SetResult(new List<FolderItem>());
        }
        catch
        {
            tcs.SetResult(new List<FolderItem>()); 
        }


    };

    try
    {
        service.GetFolderItemsAsync(_library, folder);
    }
    catch { }

    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Comment: What is the return type of `service.GetFolderItemsAsync`?

Comment: public void GetFolderItemsAsync

Comment: Your exception handling is highly bad practice. GetFolderContent should not be concerned with suppressing errors. It should relay them.

Comment: thank you for your reply, can you give me a sample ?

Comment: regarding suppressing errors ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation of the method looks good to me, although I would set the exception of the task completion source in the `catch` block, but if you prefer to ignore it that is up to you.

If you are using .NET 4.5 Your code for calling the function can be simplified to

```
var folderItemListResult = await search.GetFolderContent(folder));
```

You need to be careful when making blocking calls such as `Task.Wait` and `Task.Result`. These block the current thread and may cause a [deadlock](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html)

If you are in .NET 4.0 you calling code can be simplified to:

```
search.GetFolderContent(folder)).ContinueWith(t =>
{         
     // t is the completed task, you may need to check t.Exception
     // to see if it there was an error.

     var folderItemListResult = t.Result;
     // use the result...
});
```

Since `await` is available to you, it is easiest to use that. The method you use it in must be marked as `async` to permit the use of `await` and also it should return a `Task` or `Task<T>`, unless it is an event handler, then the return type has to be `void`.

```
public async Task GetFolderITemsAsync()
{
    var folderItemListResult = await search.GetFolderContent(folder));

    // .. use folderItemListResult
}
```

I [blogged](http://www.nedstoyanov.com/?p=8&preview=true&preview_id=8&preview_nonce=2be69a8740&post_format=standard) about this recently, you can find a lot more detail there.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Ned, I think it is very useful but I need more detail. Firstly, If i write await, it requires the method should be async. And second want continuewithit it seems good. I think i should use it but can you give me more detail about it?

Comment: no problem, what version of .net are you using? `await` is the better option but it is only available in .NET 4.5 or with the Async CTP

Comment: Actually I am using monotouchframework, i havent choose any .net framework when i was creating project but i know that it supports await, so probably it uses .net framework 4.5

Comment: I updated my answer to show how you would use `await`.

Comment: yes i know this but where i call this "var folderItemListResult = await search.GetFolderContent(folder));", should be also an async method. Its problem

Comment: no no, because in some case, it is an controller's override method. But I see all thank you for your help